# On Furstenbergs proof for infinite primes

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to understand the Furstenberg's proof of the infinitude of primes given in wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes))

If I understand correctly the last step of the proof relies on the fact that infinite union of closed sets is not closed.
How do we know this?

My line of thinking is that topological axioms only guarantee that arbitrary union of open sets is open.
The axioms cannot determine about whether infinite union of closed sets is closed or not. So, if that is the case, how do we argue that "infinite union of closed sets is not closed" in this particular proof?

(Please do correct me if my line of thinking is wrong).

Answer (score 1):

No. The proof is based on the fact that any finite union of closed sets is closed. However it is *not* true that an infinte union of closed sets is never closed.

If the set $P$ of prime numbers was finite, then the set $\bigcup_{p\in P}S(p,0)$ would be closed. But that union is equal to $\mathbb Z\setminus\{1,-1\}$, which, as it was proved previously, is *not* closed. Therefore, we have an infinite union here. In other words, $P$ is infinite.

Comment: Ok, so this particular infinite union is not closed because we know the LHS is not closed from previous arguments. Ok, now I get the logic! Thanks for the explantion!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.